# Nonstandard key signature names? (7 scale degrees)

Tags: key-signatures

I read an interesting point that when we use accidentals it might be fruitful to think of it like changing key signature (locally, I guess). So I naturally started wondering if the more exotic key signatures have names? I know *Mikrokosmos* by *Béla Bartók* have a lot of these weird key signatures but I have not found any names for them yet. Does anyone know?

So for example 1 sharp at some line or space, the others naturals, or some other combination of flat, natural and sharp on the seven possible lines and spaces. I found a maybe related article on wikipedia about [modes of the heptatonic scale and the key signature system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anhemitonic_scale#Modes_of_the_ancohemitonic_heptatonic_scales_and_the_key_signature_system) but it was a bit heavy for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as constructed doesn't meet guidelines for question quality as described in https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Specifically, there can be many equally valid answers, and the question is asking for a list.

Comment: Even the standard key signatures don't have names! There is no point in writing any naturals in a key sgnature - is there..?

Comment: What? Even the \key function in lilypond had names like \major c.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_major says "C major is one of the most common key signatures used in music.". So surely "C major" is its name.

Comment: If there are so many names for them why haven't I found a single naming convention?

Comment: I am starting to think the answer is "key of <scale>", so maybe I should find a list of scale names. Maybe things like "key of C Hungarian major" or something.

Comment: @Emil No, C-major is the name of the scale or tonality that is most prominently expressed by an empty key signature. But it is not the name of the key signature, but the name of the key. For example the key A minor shares the same key signature with the key c major.

Comment: @Lazy: That's two yeses and not a no in my book. Like how 1 is both the unit in multiplication and the first integer above 0.

Comment: @Aaron Respectfully, I'm not sure I agree that it's a "list question" so much as one in the abstract: I don't hear Emil asking that all "exotic key signatures" be listed, but *whether* they have names. Mind, it maybe should be closed because it's based on a misconception, confusing "mode" with "key signature," but that can be solved in an answer. *Is* there a word specially for non-standard key signatures that attempt to represent modes, as Bartok used? I don't think so, but just checking.

Comment: @Emil This would turn the *name* of a key signature (as you propose) into something that is not really well defined, which kind of defeats the purpose of a name. Why would an empty key signature have the name "C-major" and not "A-minor"? Or even "D-dorian", "E-phrigian", "F-lydian", "G-mixolydian" or "B-locrian"? To keep it to your "1"-example: 1 is both the multiplicative unit and the smallest positive integer. But its name (assuming having a name here made any sense) is still "1" and not "the multiplicative unit" nor "the smallest positive integer".

Comment: @Emil As it stands *keys* do have names, but *key signatures* do not really have names.

Comment: @Lazy: I don't really get your point, I was thinking of "1" as the entity and "the multiplicative unit" as one of its names, "one" being another name. But I don't want to get into a flame war here, especially since I am not a professional musician and very well could have a weird angle of viewing things.

Comment: @Emil In that case what would be the advantage of calling it "name" instead of "function"? A name does imply a certain definiteness. I guess what you actually want to ask about the names of the actual keys or scales using these key signatures. For this you will not have any very traditional name, but there have been attempts to systematic approaches to scales like Messiaen.

Comment: Why close it? Just answer and explain why there is no such list.

Comment: "I naturally started wondering if the more exotic key signatures have names": no key signatures have names, not even the standard ones.  They only have descriptions, such as "one flat" and "there sharps."

Comment: "...three sharps," of course.

Comment: @Aaron nothing here asks for a list.  The question we should close as asking for a list is "what are the names of the nonstandard key signatures."  But this is not that question.

Comment: "Even the \key function in lilypond had names like \major c": that is a function for naming _keys,_ not _key signatures._  That Wikipedia incorrectly defines C major as a key signature says more about the quality of Wikipedia as a reference than it does about music. ... Edit: Wikipedia no longer says "C major is one of the most common key signatures used in music."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you're after, but your not-quite-correct use of standard terminology is obscuring it a bit.

This isn't exactly a list, but more of a workflow:

To demonstrate, I found [*Mikrokosmos* on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRxjd2ETSo), and looked at this part:

[image: Mikrokosmos 10]

First of all, identify the tonality of the piece or passage.  I think there is [at least one good Q & A here to help with that](https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+determine+the+key).  I note that the piece concludes on D so I'll guess that it's "key" is D *something-or-other*.

It has a nonstandard signature with only A♭.

Next go to [Ian Ring's Amazing Scale Finder](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/finder.php) and select the notes corresponding to the signature:

[image: Harmonic Major]

(Never mind that it displays both G and G♯ with no A of any kind.  We just want the right set of pitch classes, spelling it only with sharps.)

It says "Harmonic Major", but **we're not done!**

Click on the link to [scale 2485](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/2485) and scroll down to where it has **Modes**.

Remember that it's considered "Harmonic Major" when we start at C.  We're starting on D, the second pitch.  The second mode of the Harmonic Major is **Dorian ♭5.**

So what you have for this piece is **D Dorian ♭5**.

If you want to read about Dorian ♭5, click the link to [scale 1645](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1645).  It will display **C** Dorian ♭5 but the properties of the scale still hold.  Maybe one day the Scale Finder will be updated to include a way to designate the tonic.

You'll also note that in the description of the Dorian ♭5 scale, there is a *list* of names for it from other traditions and naming systems.

There's another way to do this by transposing before entering the notes into the finder.  I'll leave it to the reader to work that out.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental misunderstanding here is that "key signatures" are not themselves a musical entity, but a tool for representing a musical entity in writing. This is like how time signatures represent the musical concept of meter, and staff notation represents the musical concept of pitch.

Key signatures *can help* indicate "the key," that is, the [tonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonality) of an area of music. (I hedge by saying "can help," because they don't tell us everything. They don't tell us the mode—one F# could be G major or E minor, or for that matter, perfectly serviceable for Mixolydian mode on D, or many other modes. And a piece might modulate for some time without bothering to change the key signature; we might analyze that passage as being in the new key even if the notation doesn't show it.)

To answer your core question: There may or may not be names *for* the tonalities that Bartok was representing with the "weird" key signatures in *Mikrokosmos*, but that doesn't technically make them "a name for a key signature" so much as "a name for a tonality[/mode/scale]." For example, you might want to write in the [Hungarian minor scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_minor_scale), and use an F#, an Eb, and an Ab as a key signature. In this case, to be perfectly pedantic, "Hungarian minor scale" would not be the name *of this non-standard key signature*, but of the scale that you're trying to represent.

And also, as far as I'm aware, Bartok's example is very much an outlier; there are many, many pieces in modalities other than our familiar major and minor, but they typically just use accidentals as necessary to modify "standard" key signatures.

Comment: I’m not convinced that your first sentence is necessarily true. If you can write music in a key without writing a key signature, and you can write a key signature and have music written unsigned that key signature but not in either key indicated by that key signature, then that suggests key signatures are not necessarily firmly connected to keys.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Hm... I might be getting both of us confused in abstracts—I guess, at core, every human idea "about" music is itself an abstraction, not some kind of pure, intrinsic property of music. But I am distinguishing between tonality/mode/key (a "musical thing") and key signature (a handy convenience for pointing us toward that thing. Maybe the distinction is that key signature is more a part of the practice of music than of the theory of it? Just as a "time signature" is not meter, but a way of indicating it, and "the second space of the staff" isn't intrinsically related to 440 Hz.

Comment: @ToddWilcox (Or possibly one of us is misunderstanding the other: "key signatures are not firmly connected to keys" *is* my point.)

Comment: Ok, so it might be a good idea to find seven tonality names as a header for each one of my weird key signatures, then at least one of them should be suitable for the current "home note". This should get me started on my practice project.

Comment: @Emil Well, again that would be a bit of a funny way of going about it—picking a number of flats or sharps and then finding a mode that fits it. Usually people would create the music they want to, either guided by an existing practice (e.g. blues scale) or by personal whim, and then would *normally* just adopt the key signature that matches their home note and use accidentals as needed, or, if they're Bartok, create a weird key signature. Maybe you could start a new question about this "practice project" that could shed some light?

Comment: Basically I wanted to try out a way of thinking where accidentals don't exist, only temporary key changes, and see what kind of ideas that gives me.

Comment: Also, @Emil, I forgot to mention: you read that "when we use accidentals it might be fruitful to think of it like changing key signature (locally, I guess)." This is only sometimes relevant. E.g., if you're in C and see a bunch of F# accidentals, it's a tip-off that it's "tonicizing the dominant," or feeling like G for a while. But accidentals can also just indicate neighbor notes and other alterations. The "Radetsky March," if it were in C Major, would go "E-D#-E, E-D#-E, E-D#-E-D-C," but all those D#s don't mean it's suddenly in E major or something; they're just chromatic neighbors.

Comment: @Emil After all, "accidentals" wouldn't be accidentals if there *were* no key signature; they just "make up for what the key signature doesn't do." You have a thought experiment of a world without accidentals, only "temporary key signature changes"; it's an interesting but ultimately impractical world to imagine. The opposite—all accidentals, no key signatures—is the inevitable way to go for atonal music (when there's no "tonality" aka key).

Comment: @Emil Perhaps it would be easier if you didn't think in terms of key signatures, accidentals, or even note names at all? Just pick a home note and a set of other notes from the chromatic scale to define your tonality at any given time....

Comment: @AndyBonner of course, with the origin of accidentals lying as it does in hexachord mutation, one could say that an accidental is by its very nature a temporary key signature change.  But one doesn't gain much from this realization as far as I can tell.  Film orchestras apparently use no key signatures even when playing tonal music, a fact I learned through this site.

Comment: I found a lovely site named allthescales now. I can probably use the names from there straight off the bat. Regarding your example, my thought experiment was that all the diatonic chords in the same key should "belong together", so if you wanted to jazz it up in your example you could just take any combination of notes from "E major or something". If it is possible to feel at home in all 3^7 key signatures that would make things much easier, was what I wanted to investigate. (Probably a lot of them are enharmonically the same so I can just ignore them).

Comment: Just because key signatures are not _specific_ keys does not mean they aren't musical "entities." If you strip away the conflation with specific keys, and ask what a key signature really does, it transposed the musical gamut of `ABCDEFG`. That's "real" in the sense of objective musical ideas. If add one sharp to a key signature, you transpose the gamut up a perfect fifth.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's pedantic to point out the big difference between real key signatures and a scale. There many questions in this forum based on that very misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I agree.  Furthermore, "all the scales" isn't the same as "all the keys."  For example, the key signature that denotes d major also denotes b minor, and there are also scales called d major and b minor, but there is no key called "b harmonic minor" or b melodic minor" and correspondingly no key signature for these, at least not in traditional usage.  But if you abstract key signatures sufficiently, you can use them to denote sets of pitches that aren't rotations of the A-G gamut (as Bartók does).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such list.

Part of the problem will be in the naming and various musical traditions.

For example, there is a scale called variously Freygish, Ahava Rabbah, phrygian dominant, etc. etc. Which name is supposed to be *the* name.

But I think there is another practical problem when specifically asking for *key signatures*.

In the major/minor system, a rough count of key signatures is 12 tonics * 2 modes for 24 key signatures. (Technically there are more key signatures than that, but let's skip those details.)

If you do the same, but account for *only* the seven diatonic modes, it becomes 12 * 7 or 84! Now add in additional modes from jazz theory only using each mode of the harmonic and melodic minor scale, that an additional 7 + 7 modes. 12 tonics * 21 modes is 252 key signatures!

Of course you can make a list of all those and index with all the various duplicate names, but it would become an impractical list.

One reason the circle of fifths charts of the major/minor key signatures are common is because the number of items shown is relatively small, so the visual format works. But, if you try making a chart of 200+ items, chances are it will be a mess!

The more practical way to do this is not list all *key signatures* but just list a reference scale for each mode, with each one starting on the same tonic. That will show you the interval structure of the scale, and from that you can transpose and create a key signature if you want.

That is what the wiki page *modes of the heptatonic scale and the key signature system* does. It just lists reference scales of a single tonic of `C`. It it were a list of key signatures for all those different modes, it would be 12 times as big!

Finally, there is one other issue: whether the key signature should cover all the sharp/flat naming, or if accidentals should be used in the score. For example, let's consider `D` mixolydian. A lot of music might use a key signature of `F#` and `C#` and then use naturals on any `C` in the music. In essence that says the music is roughly major, but the accidentals used to lower the seventh scale degree give it a mixolydian color. Using the conventional `D` major key signature helps make clear the tonic is `D`, but the accidentals in the score give the specifics of mode to make it mixolydian. Or... the key signature could simply be one `F#`. There is not a convention for deciding what to do. So what then to use for *the* mixolydian key signature in a giant reference list?

---

Based on all the comments on the various posts and comments I really think the OP is *not* asking about key signatures, but really is just looking for a exhaustive scale reference. There are lots of such pages online, or you can just search for scales in Wikipedia. People seem to love making those lists.

But, it might be helpful to at least point out a naming convention that appears in jazz. Lots of scales get names in jazz theory based on diatonic modes - as based on tonic `C` - plus modifiers to scale degrees. So, for example, the second mode of harmonic minor, some docs call it "locrian ♮6", because it has the same intervals as the locrian mode, but with the sixth degree raised.

Wikipedia even list the "name of scale" for the second mode of the *double harmonic scale* as "lydian ♯2 ♯6" with absolutely no citation to an actual example of music with a tonic and mode to support the idea. Basically, these kinds of docs just "name" *all* modes of *any* scale regardless is there is a real musical tradition using these purported scales.

If the question is what to call a weird scale, try using that process to find a descriptive name.

Comment: "12 tonics * 2 modes for 24 key signatures": if you allow key signatures with seven sharps or flats, there are 15 key signatures.  That each key signature can be applied to two keys (or more modes) does not change the number of key signatures.  Those 15 key signatures can denote 30 keys, though some of them are so impractical as to be arguably wrong to use.  Still, if you only allow signatures with up to 6 sharps or flats, there are 13 minor keys and 13 major keys for a total of 26 keys.  Still, that's only 13 key signatures.

Comment: @phoog, you see where I wrote "...Technically there are more key signatures than that, but let's skip those details..." In the major minor system, yes, you can the number of key signatures by just the sharp/flat account disregarding mode. But, how will that work for combining many exotic modes? For example, a key signature of one `G#` for `E` Freygish. I guess you would list one key signature and label it with the seven modes of `A` harmonic minor. Seriously, I don't know how you would arrange such stuff visually into a practical doc.

Comment: My main point with numbers was to say we would be dealing with several hundred "items", way, way more keys that the major/minor system. A combined chart/list is hard to imagine. In other words if 26 keys is 13 key signatures, from 200+ major/minor/modal/exotic "keys" how many signatures would we "need"? What's the point of trying to do that?

Comment: I would like to nitpick that I don't care about scales that much since they seem obsessed with a particular note "the tonic", for me every note in a key signature feels "home", maybe that will change or maybe not, at least I know it is important for others now.

Comment: "you see where I wrote": yes, I did see that, and I focused on the wrong point in the comment.  The main reason I decided to post the comment in spite of that disclaimer was that this answer doesn't call out the question's confusion between names of key signatures and names of keys.  I mean, it's reasonable to treat the question as if the questioner really wants to ask about keys, since that's probably the case, but the answer ought at least to point that out and then use the right terminology.  Also, as to the question "if 26 key signatures is 26 keys...," I think I'm missing your point. ...

Comment: ... Whether we think of major and minor modes, which gives 26 keys for 13 key signatures, or 4 or 6 or 7 diatonic modes, which give 52 or 78 or 91 keys for 13 signatures, the answer to "how many signatures would we need" is still 13, isn't it?  Assuming you don't allow double sharps or double flats, the number of possible key _signatures_ only grows above 13 (or 15) if you start adding them in an unconventional order, such as a key signature of G sharp and A sharp, or of D flat, which is in fact what Bartók is doing here.

Comment: Yes, unconventional "key" signatures are what the OP's question leads to. Ex. what is the "key" signature to `C` double harmonic? `Db` and `Ab`. I don't think the OP actually wants key signatures. I updated my answer accordingly.